# Can not edit a control after Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have 2 buttons (saveAll, toNextStatus)

saveAll, saves a gridview and runs Response.redirect to the same page.

toNextStatus, is shown as below.

```
    protected void toNextStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        DataTable dt = OrderDetailData.Check2to3(Session["Id"].ToString());

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lbl_Error.Text = "Please fill all fields";
            lbl_Error.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OrderDefinitionData.UpdateStatus(Session["Id"].ToString(), "3", "2");
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        }
    }
```

After executing the application, I click saveAll -> No problem it saves the gridview, I click toNextStatus it shows "Please fill all fields."

Now I want to make my toNextStatus button something like "SaveAndToNextStatus", so I want to merge the two buttons.

For that reason I add below code part into the above code

```
begv_OrderDetail.SaveClicked(sender, e); //Click event of first button saveAll
```

After executing the application, I click toNextStatus, it saves the page, but it does not show "Please fill all field"

**EDIT:**

I have a control inside my gridview(1) (dropdownlist_ship_container), and I have another gridview(2) on the same page named (ship_container_manager), when a ship_container in (1) is selected and saved, I need to refresh my page so that my ship_container_manager gets refreshed (by making delete button visiblity = false near the used containers), and hence user may not remove this container. Since my (1) is a webcontrol, I am not able to access (2) inside my (1)'s save button, so I redirect to the same page inside (1)'s save button for (2) to be refreshed

Comment: I don't understand why your save method needs to redirect to itself. That is the reason for the label not being displayed since it will get the default value. You don't need to load the page again just to update the GridView (or whatelse). So remove all `Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");` and we'll show you how to update the page correctly.

Comment: I have a control inside my gridview(1) (dropdownlist_ship_container), and I have another gridview(2) on the same page named (ship_container_manager), when a ship_container in (1) is selected and saved, I need to refresh my page so that my ship_container_manager gets refreshed (by making delete button visiblity = false near the used containers), and hence user may not remove this container. Since my (1) is a webcontrol, I am not able to access (2) inside my (1)'s save button, so I redirect to the same page inside (1)'s save button for (2) to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Do read [life cycle page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
Why do you runs Response.redirect to the same page ??

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see changes in the gridview use `gridview.databind()`

Comment: I am not able to reach to that gridview (please read edit: part in question), my gridviews are on the same page, but one of those gridview is a webcontrol and has it's save function inside of it, so I am not able to use gridview.databind() within the save function.